# How set provider to only one type of data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider, flutter-test

```
    class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
          UserLoginModel userLoginModel = UserLoginModel();
                UserLoginModel get userdata {
         return userLoginModel;
          }

           void addlogindata(UserLoginModel data) {
          userLoginModel = data;
            notifyListeners();
         }
              }
```

How to set data to this class using api or UserLoginModel through function
i want to set data like this

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.body);
  var data = UserLoginModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); userprovider.addlogindata(data);
```

bur i am getting error by doing this kind of thing

Comment: Provide the error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data=Provider.of<UserProvider>(context,listen:false);
var newdata=data.addlogindata(responsedata);
```

that work perfectly for me and now i can use that data anywhere in the app

Answer (score 1):

you can call the function like this within in the build method:

```
Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).addlogindata(data)
```

outside the build method:

```
Provider.of<UserProvider>(context,listen:false).addlogindata(data)
```